# pyttsx3 - generate subtitles file

Tags: python, pyttsx3

I have a long text file which I convert to audio file via pyttsx3 save_to_file method. I have no problem in that and it is working absolutely fine. What I am trying to do is generating a subtitle file of the audio file.

I also tried to search for it on google to no avail.

I do not want to run the audio through subtitles generator tool as it will mess up spelling of some words and punctuation marks. So, it would be better if it was generated by pyttsx3 only.